# In draft-js how apply a class to Entity to highlight it when user cursor/selection is inside that entity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Whats the best way to apply a class to an entity to highlight it when users cursor/selection is inside that entity? I've tried feeding a function down to the entity component that gets an id from parent editor component state and checks it against the entities data. But this doesn't refresh and the active class is applied permanently once user has selected entity. This seems over engineered. Am I missing a simpler way??

```
// component for textrule entity
export const TextruleComponent = props => {
  if (props.getTextruleId) {
    var id = props.getTextruleId(props.entityKey);
  }
  const entityData = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).toJS();
  const classes = classNames({ textblock: true, "textblock--active": id === entityData.data.textrule_id });
  return (
    <span className={classes} contentEditable={false}>
      {props.children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

[image]

Note after user has selected entity active class remains on both entities.

[image]